# Is there any supported way to not have a full liquid layout with clarity design?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm looking to do something where the layout caps out around 1000px (1080 / 1170 / whatever), and center the main content, sort of like the stackoverflow design (as an example, this is a super common thing). Is there a supported way to do this in clarity, or should I hack around with the menu / sidenav, etc to accomplish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to be an [open issue/request](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1464) on our end that we will be looking to incorporate. In the meantime, the best thing is writing custom CSS to manage your needs for this case. You might want comment there about your specific needs so that they are heard.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
```

Use the rows, to mimic columns.